# Como executar um outro programa pelo python?

Tags: python

Estou querendo fazer uma engine de cálculo no `Python`. Por exemplo, eu tenho um programa de nome `engine.py`, que pega uma equação e retorna as raízes. Queria escrever um outro programa de nome `interface.py`, que apenas pegaria a equação e mandaria para a engine calcular e pegaria o valor retornado. Tem como fazer isso?

engine.py

```
x = str(input())  
x = x.replace("-","+-")  
Eq = list(x.split("+"))  
b = 0  
c = 0  
if "" in Eq: Eq.remove("")  
for i in range(0,len(Eq)):
    if (Eq[i] == "x²"):    
        a = 1  
    elif (Eq[i] == "-x²"):  
        a = -1  
    elif "x²" in Eq[i]:  
        aux = Eq[i]  
        a = int(aux.replace("x²",""))  
    elif (Eq[i] == "x"):  
        b = 1  
    elif (Eq[i] == "-x"):  
        b = -1  
    elif "x" in Eq[i]:
        aux = Eq[i]
        b = int(aux.replace("x",""))
    else:
        c = int(Eq[i])
delta = (b * b) - 4 * a * c 
print("Delta:",delta)
if delta<0:
    print('Essa equacao nao tem raiz real')
elif delta==0:
    x1 = (-b)/(2*a)
    print('Raiz:',x1)
else:
    from math import sqrt
    x1 = (-b+sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
    x2 = (-b-sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
    print('Raizes:')
    print("x':",x1)
    print("x'':",x2)
```

Interface.py

```
x = input()  
y = manda_para_engine(x)
print(x)
```

alguma coisa nesse tipo

Comment: O que você já fez? clique em [edit] e adicione seu código.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim.

Defina seu arquivo `engine.py` mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
def calcular_equacao(a, b, c):
    delta = (b * b) - 4 * a * c 
    print("Delta:", delta)
    if delta<0:
        print('Essa equacao nao tem raiz real')
        return None
    elif delta==0:
        x1 = (-b)/(2*a)
        return x1
    else:
        from math import sqrt
        x1 = (-b+sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
        x2 = (-b-sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
        return (x1, x2)
```

No arquivo `interface.py`, importe `engine.py` da seguinte forma:

```
import engine
```

Para chamar a função de engine:

```
a = engine.calcular_equacao(1, 2, 3)
```

`engine.py` e `interface.py` devem estar no mesmo diretório. Fazendo um `print` de `a`, o resultado deve ser a tupla com as raízes, ou um inteiro, ou ainda `None` se não tiver raízes reais.

Repare que não direcionei a lógica de tratamento da expressão para a função. A função simplesmente é chamada com `a`, `b` e `c` já preenchidos.

Comment: ele deu um erro no `import engine`: no module named 'engine'

Comment: Você salvou o arquivo `engine.py` no mesmo diretório que chamou o Python?

Comment: sim, os dois estão no mesmo diretório, vou colocara os dois sozinhos no mesmo diretório

Comment: Agora funcionou cara, muito obrigado!!